# What data sanitzation function should be used to store entire source code of webpage?

Tags: validation, sanitization

What is the best *[data santization](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)* function to use when the entire source code of a webpage (head, body elements, etc) are going to be stored in a post meta field?

In other words, which function will encode the most html tags while avoiding dropped data?

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you need to store the entire source code of a page in the database?

Comment: We're trying to identify patterns in how people contribute to crowdfunding projects and are collecting raw data faster than we can manage it. Storing the entire source is a way to time stamp and begin to process the backload. This is for an educational project and has very limited resources, hence trying to use WP as a basic-level data warehouse. We can build a plugin to processes the meta data, save the content of the project as the_content and then use the Jetpack json api to make it available to the community.